# Filtering resources and nested resources with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: `JobCategory` and `Job`. What I would like to do is provide an initial view of data to populate a collection of Backbone models, where only the JobCategories that have Jobs are returned, and for every JobCategory, all of the *active* Jobs.

```
# models.py
class PopulatedJobCategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PopulatedJobCategoryManager,
            self).get_queryset().exclude(title='other', jobs__isnull=True)


class JobCategory(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)

    objects = models.Manager()
    populated = PopulatedJobCategoryManager()


class ActiveJobManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveJobManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            is_active=True)


class Job(models.Model):
    job_category = ForeignKey(JobCategory, related_name='jobs')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    . . .
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    active = ActiveJobManager()


# serializers.py
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.active.all()


class JobCategoryFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    jobs = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='jobs', lookup_type='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = JobCategory
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'jobs']


class JobCategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    jobs = JobSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        depth = 1
        model = JobCategory
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'jobs',)
        filter_class = JobCategoryFilter
        ordering_fields = ('order',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return JobCategory.populated.all()
```

Django Rest Framework doesn't seem to want to do any filtering at all, nor does it want to use my model managers. My desired output pseudo code is:

```
[
    {'title': '', 'jobs': [
            {'title': '', 'slug': '', 'is_active': true, ...},
            {'title': '', 'slug': '', 'is_active': true, ...},
            {'title': '', 'slug': '', 'is_active': true, ...},
            . . .
        ]
    },
    . . .
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's happening is that you're filtering on the existence of a nested job. Since parent element does have a nested job, it returns the parent element. As for an actual answer - I'm looking for the exact same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Actually, I figured something out pretty hackish based on using a `SerializerMethodField`